# Ball Chain to follow path without distortion?

Tags: path

I am trying to get a ball chain to follow a path without distortion. I learned about "Path Animation" option, but the connecting bar between the balls for the chain still do not follow the path curve properly. I separated the two elements of the chain thinking this would help but it did not. What am I doing wrong?

I am only interested in a static image.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, don't you want the cylinders to actually deform and follow the curve? Anyway, sounds like you should be using an *Array*+*Curve* modifier duo, possibly with duplifaces. See if any these help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve/47366#47366

Comment: Or these https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/how-to-scale-objects-along-the-length-of-a-curve-and-keep-them-all-facing-the-sa/68044#68044 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651 or [any of the many others](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=array%20curve%20modifier) if you search for *Array + Curve modifier*

Comment: No, the ball chain I'm attempting to replicate has rigid bars the old the balls together. The bars actually have "bells" on the end that stay inside the balls but I did not model them since they don't show.

I'd still like to understand how to do this correctly, but for now, I gave the bezier path a thickness and set free vector points around the only curved portion of the path, making it flat in those areas. It works, but I would not want to do that for a more complicated chain layout.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9nz0yhug0pxrntk/Screenshot%202017-04-13%2021.15.37.png?dl=0)