# Array along a 3d curve with rotation lock on certain axis

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i want to do an array of my instance , its a steet lamp that need to follow a road that go up and down ...

so i need an array of my instances and a curve modifier? but the problem is that my Z rotation value keep changing , according to the normal of the curve , and i dont want this because street lamp stay straight even if the road is inclined ... i tried to lock the rotation of my instance and tried to do an Z axis constraint but it dont work , i failed ? , i dont know what to do ...

im also quite confuse about every different way to do an array following a curve , i know we can use a curve modifier , a constraint , modify bezier option in propreties, and even particles ?? im lost here , dont know which technique is best for what ..

thanks

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/how-to-scale-objects-along-the-length-of-a-curve-and-keep-them-all-facing-the-sa and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier  As far as I know ou will have to make duplicates real to keep verticality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To duplicate an object without deformation and with a constraint on its Z axis, use Dupliframe:

- Build your bezier curve, and, in *Edit* mode, make sure that it goes in the right direction, if not: select all and *W* > *Switch Direction*
- Put the origin of your bezier curve at it starting point
- Put your object at the same point
- In the *Data* menu of your bezier curve, click *Path Animation*, then in *Frames* choose the amount of duplications that will happen. Enable *Follow*.
- In the *Object* menu of the object you want to duplicate, in *Duplication*, enable *Frames* and unclick *Speed*.
- Parent your object to your curve with *ctrl P* > *Object*.
- Keep your object selected and go to *Constraints*, choose *Limit Rotation*, and click X and Y, unclick Z.

It should work

[image]

Comment: woaw what a story , thanks a lot , it was so hidden ...

Comment: @DorianBorremans Don't just thank in the comments, if an answer helped you upvote it, if it solved your problem consider marking it as accepted

Comment: As the duplication feature has been removed in Blender 2.8, could you suggest another way to do this?

Comment: Yes use this method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/cant-get-my-instanced-objects-dupliverts-to-work