# Array along the curve keeping rotation and equal steps along an axis

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Is there a way to control a position of arrayed objects by a curve keeping the rotation mode and equal steps of the array along an axis?

(Detailed explanation at the screenshot applied)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/how-to-scale-objects-along-the-length-of-a-curve-and-keep-them-all-facing-the-sa/ Can't see any obvious way to achieve what you want natively, withour some sort of addons

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround using native tools, unfortunately it is destructive, so save a copy of your curve before proceeding.

Make an array of a simple plane object with the desired spacing.

Make a copy of you original curve (for safe keeping) and extrude it slightly in Z so it can encompass your plane size, then convert it to a mesh object.

On the arrayed plane add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier set to the mesh-converted curve. Adjust its settings to *Project* (so spacing remains even) and both *Positive* and *Negative* if necessary.

Now place your cubes using a particle system, adjust *Count* as necessary to match the *Array Count*$+1$ (due to a bug). Pick the cube as rendered object and turn on *Unborn* and *Died*.

Under *Rotation* set it to *None* so the cubes always face the same direction.

[image]