# How can i make the railing follow the curve on these stairs?

Tags: modifiers, edges, path

I have created a path from an edge but i don't know how to align these railing poles to the stairs. I've tried using array and curve modifier but it is all black magic to me and i cannot figure it out how to fix this.[image]

Heres the link to the blend file : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52309

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/71788#71788 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925#68925 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125095/array-along-the-curve-keeping-rotation-and-equal-steps-along-an-axis/125101 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/how-to-scale-objects-along-the-length-of-a-curve-and-keep-them-all-facing-the-sa/68044#68044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Array* and *Curve* will deform your instances.

To make non-deformed duplications, until 2.7 you could use *Dupliframes*, since 2.8 you must use *Instancing*.

If you don't need to keep a bezier curve you can do it with *Instancing* > *Verts*:

- Convert your curve to a mesh.

[image]

- Give it an *Instancing* > *Verts*.

[image]

- Select your pillar, delete the modifiers, parent it to the curve. It should be duplicated along the curve.

[image]

- You can equalize the gap between the vertices with a <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Space*. If you need to move a pillar, just move its corresponding vertex. Also, you can hide the original pillar if needed.

[image]

If you want to keep a curve, array a vertex along the curve with *Array + Curve*, select the vertex and press *Instancing > Verts*, then parent the object (that you want to instance) to the vertex.

If the duplications need to follow the direction of the curve and stay vertical you need to use another trick, see Gorgious answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/165691#165691).

Comment: Didn't saw yours when posting was probably about the same time. Yes, maybe it is the better way here to do it. Much more simple.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no simple way to do it today as *'dupliframes'* has been removed in 2.8. Or (and I hope) I am missing something...

So I don't see other solution than using hair particles to do it.

First, from your file:

You have at first steps several issues:

- Applying scales for curve and railing
- Removing rotation for the railing
- Place the railing at the origin of the curve
- Place the railing geometry above its origin

But just doing that you'll have:

[image]

and probably, you don't want that, but this:

[image]

Here you can think: ok, duplicate the rails manually... and maybe it is a good way to go if you have few rails.

However, to do it, you'll need to do the exact same thing but with a small surface, here a square, meaning using an array and a curve modifier.

But from that in order to handle the railing orientation, you'll add the railing as hair particles for the square with the following settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: oh, clever solution  ;)