# How to duplicate an object along an edge without warping or rotating it

Tags: modifiers, workflow, instances

I am trying to find a way to duplicate an object along an edge but the 3 different methods I can find either rotate the object; warp the object or give limited control. Here are images and descriptions of the tried methods as well as a manually made final result:

The first method I tried was to convert the edge to a curve and then use an array modifier and a curve modifier on the object to get it to array along the curve. The problem with this method is that It warps the object along the curve, see image below.

[image: 1]

The second method I tried was to instance the object to a plane and array the plane along the curve, this way the plane got warped but the object would remain intact. The problem with this method is I want the objects to all to be rotated the same direction but when using this method it rotates the objects in the corners, see image below.

[image: 3]

The third and final method I found was to instance the object along the vertices, while this neither rotates or warps the object, it gives me very little control over spacing and forces me to add an object on every corner or existing vertices on the edge. The amount of work to make sure there is even spacing between all the vertices and getting them placed where I want them would be just as much work if not more so than just manually duplicating and placing the objects, see image below.

[image: 2]

Is there some way I can get my object to be duplicated along an edge that neither rotates or warps my object. For an example of intended result see image below.

[image: 4]

Comment: Have you tried particle instances?

Comment: Yup, second method+particle system

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125095/array-along-the-curve-keeping-rotation-and-equal-steps-along-an-axis/125101#125101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of arraying a plane along the curve, try arraying a simple vertex. Tweak the constant offset in the array modifier to get the desired offset.

[image]

Then create the object you want to instance. Set its parent to the "Arrayed vertices" object. Go to the parent object and in the object properties. Set the instancing to "Verts".
[image]

Don't forget to add a high enough resolution in the curve properties or else there may be unwanted interpolation.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Better than particles for interactive visual feedback here, easier to work with. Congrats. Probably good to mention the Curve Resolution, they slides here too.

Comment: This works and is really convenient to work with, I would like to add that while increasing the curve resolution reduces how far off the path it still does slightly stray from the path, however, if you set the resolution to 1 it perfectly follows the curve. For example see: https://imgur.com/a/jBCMoTP

Comment: I noticed the opposite ! Anyways, glad it helped

Comment: While trying to replicate why it snapped to the corner better with the resolution at 1 I noticed it only works under specific circumstances. For an example of a curve where it's beneficial to use a resolution of 1 and an example of when it's not, see images: https://imgur.com/a/JRsntGS

Answer (score 3):

- Particle system from single vertex
- Particles Rendered as Object
- Curve with Physics Properties > Force Field > Curve Guide

[image]

- Distance can be adjusted by number of particles

Edit Note: increace Curve resolution in Data Properties > Shape > Resolution Preview U to max (64) to avoid sliding in corners

[image]

Or use Instances from Vertices seems to me as ideal solution for its even distribution. For more flexibility use Subdivision Surface modifier.

[image]

Comment: You can considerably improve (but no totally fix) corner accuracy by increasing curve object resolution (even if it has no visual effect)

Comment: Yes, particles now goes cross corner. Thanks :)