# Why isn't instancing duplicating an object along a curve in 2.82?

Tags: instances, dupli-groups

Instancing is the name of the panel in 2.8. Instantiate child objects. This may have been called dupliverts and duplifaces in the past.

I cannot get a simple curve duplicate instantiation to succeed in 2.8 and 2.82.

My expectation is that I would get a duplicate for every point on the curve.  I only get one duplicate following the first point of the curve. Is my expectation correct?

[image]

In comparison I do get the expected result for a simple mesh with instancing. One duplicate for each vertex.

The barely visible relationship lines shows parent child.

Am I missing a simple step?

I am not trying to use the Array Modifier and the Curve Modifier.

Comment: As far as I know dipliverts work only with mesh object vertex, bezier curve nodes have never been supported

Comment: As a workaround you can use a vertex with an array modifier set to fit the curve and a curve modifier, then tweak the array settings to get the expected result : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167066/86891 Edit : oops didn't see the last sentence. Ignore that

Comment: There is a delete comment feature in Stack Exchange.