# Evenly space out object instances from array modifier in curve

Tags: modifiers

I'm currently in the process of creating a fence that follows the same path as a curve. I simply created a fence (starting off with a simple model, which I can and might change later when I got this figured out), arrayed this (fit curve) and added the curve modifier. All set, you'd think. However, this is not the case.

Some fence posts along the curve are smaller in it's width than other instances of the fence posts.

First, I added the array modifier:
[image]

All fence posts are evenly spread out, as they should. However, when I add the curve modifier, it's starting to show the weird behaviour:
[image]

Firstly, it went a bit left on the x-axis. Secondly, as you can see (especially the last few fence posts), some are spaced out less than others.

What did I do wrong or what do I need to change so that the fence posts are evenly spread across the curve?

Bonus question: Before I add the curve modifier, the last post on the right is slightly after the curve ends. This could be solved by reducing the offset between posts ever so slightly. Is there a way to do this as precise as possible? A calculation, a function or whatever?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125095

Comment: Is there a non-destructive method? I like to not apply modifiers whenever possible, so it's easier to change things.